# "Run-time error 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" when running VBA code a second time

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

The code below is **working fine the first time I run it, but when I need to run it a second time**, it gives me this error:

> Run Time error '462': the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

It doesn't happen all the time so I suppose it has something to do with Word (not) running in the background...? What am I missing here?

```
Sub Docs()

Sheets("examplesheet").Select

Dim WordApp1 As Object
Dim WordDoc1 As Object

Set WordApp1 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp1.Visible = True
WordApp1.Activate

Set WordDoc1 = WordApp1.Documents.Add

Range("A1:C33").Copy

WordApp1.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, _
Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

WordDoc1.PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
WordDoc1.PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
WordDoc1.PageSetup.BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)

' Control if folder exists, if not create folder
If Len(Dir("F:\documents\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "F:\documents\" & Year(Date)
End If

WordDoc1.SaveAs "F:\documents\" & Year(Date) & "\examplename " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & ".docx"

WordDoc1.Close
'WordApp1.Quit

Set WordDoc1 = Nothing
Set WordApp1 = Nothing

Windows("exampleworkbook.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("examplesheet").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select


' export sheet 2 to Word
Sheets("examplesheet2").Select

Set WordApp2 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp2.Visible = True
WordApp2.Activate

Set WordDoc2 = WordApp2.Documents.Add

Range("A1:C33").Copy

WordApp2.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, _
Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

WordDoc2.PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
WordDoc2.PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
WordDoc2.PageSetup.BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)

WordDoc2.SaveAs "F:\files\" & Year(Date) & "\name" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & ".docx"

WordDoc2.Close
'WordApp2.Quit

Set WordDoc2 = Nothing
Set WordApp2 = Nothing

Windows("exampleworkbook.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("examplesheet2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

' Variables Outlook
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngCc As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim rngAttach1 As Range
Dim rngAttach2 As Range
Dim numSend As Integer

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

' Outlook
On Error GoTo handleError

With Sheets("Mail")
    Set rngTo = .Range("B11")
    Set rngCc = .Range("B12")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("B13")
    Set rngBody = .Range("B14")
    Set rngAttach1 = .Range("B15")
    Set rngAttach2 = .Range("B16")
End With

With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .Cc = rngCc.Value
    '.Body = rngBody.Value
    .Body = "Hi," & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            rngBody.Value & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Kind regards,"
    .Attachments.Add rngAttach1.Value
    .Attachments.Add rngAttach2.Value
    .Display
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
     Application.SendKeys "%s"
  ' .Send       ' Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With

numSend = numSend + 1

GoTo skipError

handleError:
numErr = numErr + 1
oFile.WriteLine "*** ERROR *** Email for account" & broker & " not sent. Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
skipError:

On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Sent emails: " & numSend & vbNewLine & "Number of errors: " & numErr, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Operation finished"

GoTo endProgram

cancelProgram:
MsgBox "No mails were sent.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Operation cancelled"

endProgram:
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing
Set rngAttach1 = Nothing
Set rngAttach2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What line of code produces the error?

Comment: If you run this through and then open the Task Manager, do you have a winword.exe in the Processes list?

Comment: @MatthewD WordDoc1.PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.4)

Comment: Do you have a reference set to Word? If not, constants like `wdPasteRTF` and `wdInLine` are empty variables. Also, why aren't you quitting the Word instances you open?

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, 2 times actually.

Comment: In addition to not closing the Word instances you open. You don't need to create 2 separate word instances. You can have one instance and as many documents as you need. Then close that instance. You may also wish to use early binding (if you know everyone using the code will have the reference to Word set (or will be using it from the same Excel file).

Comment: where you do `dim wordapp1 as object`; would you need to do the same for `wordapp2` and declare it as an object variable? (same for `wordDoc2`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First problem : [Run-time error '462'](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178510) : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

The issue here is the use of :

1. Late Biding : `Dim Smthg As Object` or
2. Implicit references : `Dim Smthg As Range` instead of 
   `Dim Smthg As Excel.Range` or `Dim Smthg As Word.Range`

So you **need to fully qualified all the variables that you set** (I've done that in your code)

---

---

### Second problem

**You work with multiple instances** of Word and you **only need one to handle multiple documents**.

So instead of creating a new one each time with :

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

You can get an open instance (if there is one) or create one with that code :

```
On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
```

And **once you've put this at the start** of your proc, you can **use this instance until the end** of the proc and **before the end, quit it** to avoid having multiple instances running.

---

Here is your code reviewed and cleaned, take a look :

```
Sub Docs()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

' Control if folder exists, if not create folder
If Len(Dir("F:\documents\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir "F:\documents\" & Year(Date)

' Get or Create a Word Instance
On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Workbooks("exampleworkbook.xlsm").Sheets("examplesheet").Range("A1:C33").Copy

With WordApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    Set WordDoc = .Documents.Add
    .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, _
                Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

With Application
    .Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

With WordDoc
    .PageSetup.TopMargin = WordApp.CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = WordApp.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = WordApp.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .SaveAs "F:\documents\" & Year(Date) & "\examplename " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & ".docx"
    .Close
End With

' export sheet 2 to Word
Workbooks("exampleworkbook.xlsm").Sheets("examplesheet2").Range("A1:C33").Copy

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
WordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, _
                        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

With WordDoc
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = WordApp.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .PageSetup.TopMargin = WordApp.CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = WordApp.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .SaveAs "F:\files\" & Year(Date) & "\name" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") & ".docx"
    .Close
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
WordApp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

' Variables Outlook
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rngTo As Excel.Range
Dim rngCc As Excel.Range
Dim rngSubject As Excel.Range
Dim rngBody As Excel.Range
Dim rngAttach1 As Excel.Range
Dim rngAttach2 As Excel.Range
Dim numSend As Integer


On Error Resume Next
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0


Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

' Outlook
On Error GoTo handleError

With Sheets("Mail")
    Set rngTo = .Range("B11")
    Set rngCc = .Range("B12")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("B13")
    Set rngBody = .Range("B14")
    Set rngAttach1 = .Range("B15")
    Set rngAttach2 = .Range("B16")
End With

With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .CC = rngCc.Value
    '.Body = rngBody.Value
    .Body = "Hi," & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            rngBody.Value & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Kind regards,"
    .Attachments.Add rngAttach1.Value
    .Attachments.Add rngAttach2.Value
    .Display
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
     Application.SendKeys "%s"
  ' .Send       ' Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With

numSend = numSend + 1

GoTo skipError

handleError:
numErr = numErr + 1
oFile.WriteLine "*** ERROR *** Email for account" & broker & " not sent. Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
skipError:

On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Sent emails: " & numSend & vbNewLine & "Number of errors: " & numErr, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Operation finished"

GoTo endProgram

cancelProgram:
MsgBox "No mails were sent.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Operation cancelled"

endProgram:
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing
Set rngAttach1 = Nothing
Set rngAttach2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code, but running it twice still gives me the same 462 error on this line: `.PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.4)`

Comment: In facts, it seems to be coming from the Typing of your variables, let me finish to review this and edit my post! ;)

Comment: That's exactly what Cindy Meister suggested and it works. Because you also reviewed my code, I marked this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thx, take a look at the post edit, I included some explanations about the error that was fixed! ;)

Answer (score 4):

If this is running in Excel then you probably need to specify that CentimetersToPoints is coming from the Word library. As it stands, VBA has to guess and sometimes it probably can't find it. So try:

```
wdApp.CentimetersToPoints
```