# 'Run-time error 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable” during 2nd iteration

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am aware this is very close to other questions but I have failed to identify my problem through other posted solutions which is why I am posting it now. I have indicated in the code where the error pops up during the 2nd iteration. Here is an example of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631641/run-time-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable) as well.

```
Sub ExcelToWOrdCopy()

Dim objWord As Word.Application

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 3 To LR

Call PrintScreen 'Print screen set in a module and works fine

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\a222012\Desktop\EDD Results File.docx")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ScreenShot").Range.Paste 'Bookmarks have been placed in above word document.

ActiveSheet.Range("C2:L2").Copy

objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LinkName").Range.Paste
objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

'Error on next line during 2nd iteration

objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor

objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderRight).LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderRight).Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Cells(x, 3), Cells(x, 12)), Text
Range(Cells(x, 3), Cells(x, 12)).Copy

objWord.Visible = True
objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Links").Range.Paste
objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(2).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 ("C:\Users\a222012\Desktop\EDD\" & (Cells(3, 1) & " - " & Cells(x, 1)))
objWord.Quit

Next x

Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The A to the Q you linked talks about only needing to create one instance of Word.  Yours creates one for each iteration.  Follow the advise in that A and see what happens

Comment: Also, since you have referenced the Word library, use early binding. `Set objWord = New Word.Application`

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you for your response. I was being really silly and didn't pay careful enough attention to the linked similar question. For anyone reading this with a similar problem my fix was referencing the word library on either side of the `=` sign. i.e instead of `objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle` it supposed to be `objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = objWord.Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle` such that  `objWord` appears on both sides.

Comment: `wdBorderBottom` and other `wd*` constants won't be defined in Excel.  Unless you have `Option Explicit` (and you should have) they will be created and default to 0.  They should be qualified with `objWord`

Comment: Agreed, I am fairly new to VBA and that's all the more reason to be using `Option Explicit`. I will make every effort to start using it more religiously. Especially if I am making these types of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the other answer and in comments,
it is better (and more stable) to create/use only ONE instance of Word in your loop.

I've also added a few `With` to improve code readability and performances :

```
Sub ExcelToWOrdCopy()
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim wS As Excel.Worksheet
'''Change sheet's name below
Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'''This will use existing instance of Word if there is one, or create a new one
On Error Resume Next
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If objWord Is Nothing Then Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

    LR = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 3 To LR
        Call PrintScreen 'Print screen set in a module and works fine

        Set oDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\a222012\Desktop\EDD Results File.docx")

        With oDoc
            .Bookmarks("ScreenShot").Range.Paste 'Bookmarks have been placed in above word document.

            wS.Range("C2:L2").Copy
            objWord.Visible = True
            .Bookmarks("LinkName").Range.Paste

            With .Tables(1)
                .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
                With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
                    .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
                    .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
                    .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
                End With '.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
                With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
                    .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
                    .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
                    .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
                End With '.Borders(wdBorderRight)
            End With '.Tables(1)

            wS.Hyperlinks.Add Range(wS.Cells(x, 3), wS.Cells(x, 12)), Text
            wS.Range(wS.Cells(x, 3), wS.Cells(x, 12)).Copy

            objWord.Visible = True
            .Bookmarks("Links").Range.Paste
            .Tables(2).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
            DoEvents
            .SaveAs2 ("C:\Users\a222012\Desktop\EDD\" & (Cells(3, 1) & " - " & Cells(x, 1)))
        End With 'oDoc
    Next x
objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you R3uK :) works well. I did initially have the `with` portion but removed it during debugging to see if I was missing something. Sometimes different eyes is the quickest way to solve silly mistakes lol