# Excel To Word VBA - The Remote Server Machine Does not exist

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am running a VBA code from Excel to Word.
First time it always goes fine. The second time it runs, it receives a runtime error.
"462 - The Remote Server Machine Does not exist or is unavailable"
This goes on alternately.

If you try this code in Excel, you can see it runs ok. Close the Word app then run it again, the error is there. Any ideas?

```
Sub Test()

Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Open the Word App

objWord.Visible = True 'Make Word App visible

Dim wrdDoc As Object
Set wrdDoc = objWord.Documents.Add 'Make New Word Document


        'Heading
        wrdDoc.Content.InsertAfter ("Title Here")    'Make a line
        wrdDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Style = "Heading 1"   'Make this line in Heading Format
        
        
        'Make this line into a numbered list
        wrdDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
        ContinuePreviousList:=True, _
        ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
        

End Sub
```

Comment: May not be your problem, but you're using a number of Word constants and you also seem to be using late binding, so Excel VBA will not know the values of those constants.

Comment: Have you tried what was mentioned in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631641/run-time-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams. Thanks for your answer. I think what you said is the cause of my problem. It should be ListTemplate:= objWord.ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery). The error is gone now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan. You are a savior. I looked at similar posts with the same error but the link that you sent gave the answer. I made it into ListTemplate:= objWord.ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery). If you want, please post an answer to this question and I'll mark as correct. Thanks a lot!