# "Run-time error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" occurs when VBA code run more than once

Tags: excel, vba, reflection, ms-word, microfocus

The code below runs when I run through it the first time but fails when I run it again. So far, the only way it works if I completely shut down my program and re-open it.

```
Public Sub OpenEmulator()
    'Declare an object variable for the Reflection object
    Dim app As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject
   
    'Declare additional Reflection objects, such as frame, terminal, and view
    Dim frame As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.frame
    Dim terminal As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts.IbmTerminal
    Dim view As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.view
   
    'Create a new instance of Reflection
    Set app = New Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject
 
    'wait until Reflection initializes
    Do While app.IsInitialized = False
        app.Wait (200)
    Loop
 
    'Create controls to open and display the session document.
    Set frame = app.GetObject("Frame")
    frame.Visible = True
   
    Set terminal = app.CreateControl2("09E5A1B4-0BA6-4546-A27D-FE4762B7ACE1")
                          
    terminal.HostAddress = "sourcehost"
    Set view = frame.CreateView(terminal)
    Set screen = terminal.screen
End Sub
```

I have looked up this issue and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631641/run-time-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable) regarding the same problem. However, I don't see any implicit reference problems in my code.

When I debug, the error occurs on the final line when calling terminal.screen. I'm clearly missing something but can anyone provide any help?

Comment: that shouldn't be the error why (since you write that it runs correctly at least once) but ... "terminal. Screen" has a space after the dot

Comment: sorry that was a typo that must've occurred when pasting over here. I've edited it now.